# Cartopy: wrong longitude labels when plotting regional maps

Tags: python, cartopy

I tried to plot regional map between 119degE and 90degW but something wrong with my longitude labels. Here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

lats = -31
latn =  31
lon1 = 119  
lon2 = 301   

plt.figure()                            
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=210)    
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)   
ax.set_extent([lon1, lon2, lats, latn], proj)  
ax.coastlines()                   
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(120,330,30) ,crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-30, 40,10) ,crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
lon_formatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
lat_formatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)     

ax.set_ylabel(' ')   
ax.set_xlabel(' ')
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

Here are the problems:

1. I set `ax.set_extent` with longitude range given by `lon1` and `lon2`. But the figure shows the global longitude.
2. The longitude tick labels are wrong (should be 120E, 150E, 180, 150W, ...).

How to fix these issues?

The version of `cartopy` I use is v0.20.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gridlines()` function with proper settings. Note, the option `crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()` is used in the function to get correct geographic longitudes.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

lats = -31
latn =  31
lon1 = 119  
lon2 = 301   

plt.figure(figsize=[9,6])                            
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=210)    
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)   
ax.set_extent([lon1, lon2, lats, latn], proj)  
ax.coastlines()

gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, 
                  xlocs=np.arange(-150,360,30), ylocs=np.arange(-30, 40,10), 
                  x_inline=False, y_inline=False, linewidth=0.33, color='k',alpha=0.5)
gl.right_labels = False
gl.top_labels = False

ax.set_ylabel(' ')   
ax.set_xlabel(' ')
plt.show()
```

[image: world]

Comment: Thanks! The results make much more sense.